# How can I remove the default button of a fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[image: fragmentcapture]

I'm developing an app with many fragments and each fragment has a button by default in the top-left corner. When I press that small button nothing happens. How can I remove it?
Thanks!

[image: Captura]
I didn't try anything, but I was thinking that I have to remove the onButtonPressed method, but I'm not sure

This is the code of a fragment 
        package com.flixarts.ar.*;

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
     * {@link schoolfragment0.OnFragmentInteractionListener}     interface
     * to handle interaction events.
     * Use the {@link schoolfragment0#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
public class schoolfragment0 extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public schoolfragment0() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment schoolfragment0.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static schoolfragment0 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    schoolfragment0 fragment = new schoolfragment0();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schoolfragment0, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

I want to delete the button that's grey in the top left corner

This is the XML

```
<FrameLayout                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".schoolfragment0">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/espacioFrases"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/espacioFrasesTraducidas"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In the XML I have two textviews (I've covered, sorry, I can't find where is that button)

Comment: Presumably that button is in `res/layout/fragment_schoolfragment0.xml` somewhere.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare I can't find that button, it comes by default when I create a Fragment do you see that in my XML? I will appreciate if you can help me

Comment: No, it's not in that layout file. Perhaps that is supposed to be a `Toolbar` and there is a theme problem. Perhaps it is something else added by your activity. Use Android Studio's Layout Inspector to find out what the widget ID is, then see if that gives you any clues.